# Same SSL for multiple domains

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, domain, godaddy

I have a Godaddy domain that points to aws load balancer with a SSL cert.

Now I want to add another domain B to point to the same load balancer.

1. Can I use the same SSL cert or is it associated with the domain name ?
2. Do I have to buy a [UCC ssl cert](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3908/what-is-a-multiple-domain-ucc-ssl-certificate) ? What is it anyway ?
3. How should I approach this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL certificates are tied to a particular domain, so no to #1.

2 works nicely as an option. A UCC/SAN certificate is just an SSL certificate with multiple valid domain names in it (called Subject Alternative Names). UCC/SAN is what I use for our Amazon AWS load balancer and it works nicely.

The only downside of such a certificate is that it shows the other domain names it's used for. If you have paranoid/picky clients this may be problematic.

Comment: Sounds like what I need thanks ! Will I need to revoke the old cert in the load balancer and in domain A to use this one ?

Comment: how about the option of having 2 ssl certs for the same domain different LBs and use route 53 to direct to the correct LB ?

Comment: @Michael Why would you have two SSL certificates for the same domain? Both LBs can use the same certificate.